# popover getting cut inside the bootstrap datatable

Tags: datatable, popover

My Popover is getting cut in bootstrap datatable

[image]

Comment: <a class=\"mytooltip\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" style=\"z-index:10000\">icon<span class=\"tooltip-content5\" style=\"z-index:10000\"><span class=\"tooltip-text3\" style=\"z-index:10000\"><span class=\"tooltip-inner2\" style=\"z-index:10000\">Howdy, Ben!<br /> There are 13 unread messages in your inbox.</span></span></span></a>

Comment: My code for line tooltip